# Shopify API HTTP POST redirecting instead of POSTing

Tags: post, shopify, windows-server-2016

I have code (Classic ASP) which was recently working POSTing orders to Shopify but has now stopped POSTing and either creates an error "A Redirection problem has occurred" or redirects to the admin area of the Shopify site, depending on which XMLHTTP component I employ.  The code below still works on older OS but not on Server 2016 where I am working.

I can't find much on Google but there was an indication in the Shopify Forum that the problem was a result of cookies (I have set none) and that this is overcome by sending a header containing X-Shopify-Access-Token:.  I tried this using the "Authorize" setRequestHeader but it made no difference, or I got the syntax wrong or something.  I used

```
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "Authorization","X-Shopify-Access-Token=<token>"
```

Below is the code that worked a few weeks back. Variable `jsondata` contains valid JSON to send to create an order.

```
Set xmlhttp = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.3.0")
    xmlhttp.Open "POST", "https://<api key>:<passowrd>@<sitename>.myshopify.com/admin/orders.json", false, "<api key>", "<password>"
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8"
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Length", Len(jsondata)
    xmlhttp.Send jsondata   
Set xmlhttp = nothing
```

I expect a POST and a JSON order response but this is not happening - just a redirection to `https://<sitename>.myshopify.com/admin`.  Any ideas anyone?

Comment: Shopify changed their API requests from `/admin/api/orders.json` to `/admin/api/2019-04/orders.json` where it includes the stable API version for a specific month and year. Maybe the problem is there since your doesn't have them.

Comment: Mmm.  I tried that.  Should have left that in but it is the code without that which is working on older OSs.  I'm sure it would work with that as well.